# Regex to validate dates in this format d/m/yyyy

Tags: regex

I found a [regex](http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=409) that works wonders,but it forces leading 0's on month and day and I need to accept dates that have the month and/or day in a single digit format

Comment: Why not try to parse it into a timestamp object, and simply reject it if you are unable to parse it? There should be no need for the extra regex step in the middle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested this with REGex Tester:

```
^(((0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\/(0?[13578]|1[02])\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0?[1-9]|[12]\d|30)\/(0?[13456789]|1[012])\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\/0?2\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29\/02\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0?[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$
```

This is the same @ant18 linked, but I added `?` for every leading `0`.

**EDIT:** sry misread the asker's name, corrected

Comment: Still dies on february dates... I'm missing something.

Comment: Got it, left out the one 0 :)

Answer (score 1):

`^(((0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\/(0?[13578]|1[02])\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0?[1-9]|[12]\d|30)\/(0?[13456789]|1[012])\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\/0?2\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29\/0?2\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0?[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$`

Same as your provided regexp with optional leading 0s.

Answer (score 0):

this will do it:

```
var rx = /^(3[0-1]|[0-2]?[0-9])\/(1[0-2]|0?[0-9])\/[0-9]{4}$/;

   rx.text('01/01/2000'); //true

   rx.text('1/1/2000'); //true

   rx.text('32/1/2000'); //false

   rx.text('1/13/2000'); //false
```

However this will not really ensure a valid date since it will allow dates like 31/2/2000

To parse a date, and validate it split on `/` and use `new Date` to create a date object from the values, then extract the same values and see if they match, if not the date is invalid :)