# oracle regex_replace to keep digit and backslash

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, date, regexp-like

I have excel file that contains some junk data in date field.

the date format is in 1/2/2015 format. I'm trying to load that file into a stage table in varchar field and apply regex replace function to clean up the bad data before loading to main table

can i somebody provide me the suitable experssion for this

```
create table A
(
bad_date varchar2(4000)
);

insert into A
( bad_date)
values ('1/2/2005');
insert into A
( bad_date)
values ('indep');
insert into A
( bad_date)
values ('/');

commit;


 create table B
    (
    good_date date
    );
```

I want to use regex function to cleanse the data which is not in the date pattern. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `^[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{4}` pattern for *regexp_like* conforming your date format.

Use the following *insert* statement to get clean date data :

```
insert into B
select * from
( select to_date(bad_date,
           case when 
             regexp_like(bad_date,'^[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{4}') then 
             'DD/MM/YYYY'
           end) dateConverted          
    from A)
where dateConverted is not null;
```

[*SQL Fiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/05b73f/3)

Answer (score 3):

You can come close with something like:

```
select (case when regexp(bad_date, '^[0-1]?[0-9]/[0-3]?[0-9]/[0-9]{4}$')
             then to_date(bad_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY'
        end) as converted_date
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the following:

```
INSERT INTO B (GOOD_DATE)
  SELECT TO_DATE(BAD_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
    FROM A
    WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(BAD_DATE, '[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+')
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d3e96/7)

Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

I am inclined to contribute a more mature regex to match valid dates in `m/d/yyyy` format:

```
INSERT INTO B (GOOD_DATE)
  SELECT TO_DATE(BAD_DATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
    FROM A
    WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(BAD_DATE,
            '^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/(0?[1-9]|1[012])\/(19|20)[0-9][0-9]$'
    )
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dade73/18)

Inspired by

- [Regex to validate dates in this format d/m/yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904114/regex-to-validate-dates-in-this-format-d-m-yyyy)
- https://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html